# Browser-Sync - changes to .scss not appearing in browser but appearing in .css

Tags: npm, sass, gulp, browser-sync, gulp-watch

I am trying to set up a project with browser-sync in Gulp 4. When executing my default task "gulp"- browser-sync does load and launches an instance of chrome at local:3000 and all changes made in my "src" folder to *.html files reload as expected after saving. However, anything in my "sass" folder as "*.scss" is compiled correctly and moved to my "dist" folder as a ".css" after saving, however, any changes are not reloaded into my browser upon saving.

I have tried re-arranging the position of browserSync.reload so that it takes place before any minimizing but that did not solve the issue. I have tried looking at the browsersync + Gulp.js doc but to no avail. I am still new with Gulp 4 and learning so it is very possible I have just mucked up something in the code or am trying to execute a series of commands that do not work together well.

```
/* REQUIRED PACKAGES EDITED */

var gulp = require('gulp');
    watch = require('gulp-watch');
    browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
    concat = require('gulp-concat');
    sass = require('gulp-sass');
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
    pump = require('pump');
    cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');

/* GULP TASKS */

/* Pipe .HTML to Dist Folder */

gulp.task('html', function(cb) {
  pump([
    gulp.src('src/*.html'),
    gulp.dest('dist'),
    browserSync.stream()
  ],
  cb
  );
});

/* Clean and Pipe .SCSS to Dist Folder */

gulp.task('sass', function(cb) {
  pump([
    gulp.src('src/sass/*.scss'),
    sass().on('error', sass.logError),
    cleanCSS(),
    gulp.dest('dist/css'),
    browserSync.stream()
  ],
  cb
  );
});

gulp.task('sass:watch', function(){
  gulp.watch('src/sass/*.scss', ['sass']);
});

/* Concat, Uglify & Pipe .JS to Dist Folder */

gulp.task('js', function(cb) {
  pump([
    gulp.src('src/js/*.js'),
    concat('main.js'),
    uglify(),
    gulp.dest('dist/js'),
    browserSync.stream()
  ],
  cb
  );
});

/* Minify & Pipe .IMG to Dist Folder */

gulp.task('imagemin', function(cb) {
  pump([
    gulp.src('src/img/*'),
    imagemin(),
    gulp.dest('dist/img'),
    browserSync.stream()
  ],
  cb
  );
});

/* Browser-Sync */

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
  browserSync.init({
      server: {
          baseDir: './src'
      }
  });
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {

  gulp.watch('./src/sass/*.scss', gulp.series('sass'));
  gulp.watch('./src//js/*.js', gulp.series('js'));
  gulp.watch('./src/*.html', gulp.series('html'));

});

/* RUN DEFAULT - RUN ALL TASKS */

gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('html', 'sass', 'js', 'imagemin', 'browser-sync', 'watch'));
```

I would expect everything to function but again, upon any changes made to the .scss file, they take place and are saved to the .css file but the changes do not appear in the browser. Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
gulp.watch('./src/sass/*.scss', gulp.series('sass'), browserSync.reload);
```

to:

```
gulp.watch('./src/sass/*.scss', gulp.series('sass', browserSync.reload));
```

Also in this:

```
gulp.task('sass', function(cb) {
   pump([
     gulp.src('src/sass/*.scss'),

     // don't call browserSync.stream() before sass()
     // plus you already have it in your scss watch to reload
     // so either move this to the end - after gulp.dest - and remove it from the watch
     // or remove it from here and leave in the watch

     //  browserSync.stream(),

     sass().on('error', sass.logError),
     cleanCSS(),
     gulp.dest('dist/css')
   ],

   cb;
  );
 });
```

---

```
// in your watch task:

gulp.watch("./src/*.html", { events: 'all' }, function(cb) {
    browserSync.reload();
    cb();
  });



gulp.task('html', function(cb) {
  pump([
    gulp.src('src/*.html'),
    gulp.dest('dist'),
    //  browserSync.stream()
  ],
  cb
  );
});
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestions! I gave them a try and although they seemed to improve the processing of the gulp default task, I'm still receiving only a white background although I have it set to black currently in the .scss. Anything else you can suggest that may be the issue or any additional info I can provide?

Comment: Then I would try putting a browserSync.stream()  call in your html task right after the gulp.dest and change to this:   gulp.watch('./src/*.html', gulp.series(html));

Comment: I noticed the issue with that was I had set gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel...) to gulp.series on accident so no issue with piping the .scss to .css anymore. So all files are loading into the dist folder correctly, just not interpreting the information in .scss (src) to .css (dist) to the browser upon save.

Comment: Did you try putting the browserSync.stream() call after the gulp.dest in the 'sass' task?

Comment: Yes, I edited the original code above to what it is currently! Also, I really appreciate the help here, thank you.

Comment: Last suggestions for tonight edited in my answer above.  If it isn't working tomorrow I can run your code in a test environment to see things better.

Comment: Actually, given your suggestions- when I change the baseDir to ./dist in the browser-sync task instead of ./src, everything works flawlessly. Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome.  Mind upvoting the answer as well (the upArrow above the 0 above the check).  Thanks.

Comment: I have- I think I am too new on here so it doesn't appear but it says it is still recorded!